# jquery assumes element id? normal behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                console.log(foo); // jQuery assumes foo is an id?
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo">i'm a div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the console outputs:

`<div id="foo">i'm a div</div>`

why?

Comment: Not specific to jQuery, but Javascript. Never noticed this before, good question. Here is a fiddle which demonstrates the above: http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/rjwPA/1

Comment: It's finding `window.foo`, which is the element by ID.

Comment: This is coincidentally a good demonstration of why `id`s need to be unique in the DOM, and how otherwise the behavior would be undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with jQuery.

This is because named elements(elements with an `ID` or `name` attribute) become properties of the window object.

`console.log(foo)` is identical to `console.log(window.foo);`

Since your `div` is a named element(`id="foo"`), it is added to `window`.

[**Named access on window**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

Comment: Not in every browser however and it's not part of the spec.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a jQuery behavior, it's (originally) an Internet Explorer behavior. IE has always created global variables for each DOM element that has an `id` attribute. The variable is named after the `id` and references the DOM element. Lately, other browsers have been following suit.

- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Mar/22/Internet-Explorer-Global-Variable-Blow-ups
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/10/22/internet-explorer-creates-global-variables-for-each-object-in-the-dom.aspx
- http://www.shanison.com/2010/06/17/ie-id-and-javascript-global-variable/
- http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html

Answer (score 0):

JQuery doesn't assume that, but rather JavaScript does. Your `foo` is unquoted, so it must either be an identifier or undefined. The element with id `foo` happens to be in the scope of your script, so the element identified by it is logged.

If you renamed it to `bar`, then you'd be able to reference `bar` as it'd be a top-level id.

Note that such usage is frowned upon because it is unclear what you're doing in the code without referencing the html. Using `document.getElementById(...)` or a variant thereof is generally preferred because it is clear what you're doing.